# z:net.snowflake.spark.snowflake.Utils.runQuery. : java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: python, apache-spark, hadoop, pyspark, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

As per my use case, I am trying to write data from s3 to the snowflake. My application is written in Python/Pyspark and is running on the AWS EKS cluster.

The code is:

```
def write_from_audience_parquet_to_snowflake(self):
    self.logger.info('write_from_audience_parquet_to_snowflake started')

    path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
    parquet_stage = read_template(path + '/sql/staging_audience_attribute.sql')
    input_base_s3 = self.base_input_s3_path.replace("s3a://", "s3://")

    self.logger.info("input_base_s3 = {}".format(input_base_s3))

    parquet_stage = parquet_stage.render(input_base_s3=input_base_s3, mab_id=self.mab_id,
                                         mab_send_id=self.mab_send_id, access_key=self.aws_access_key,
                                         secret_key=self.aws_secret_key, session_token=self.aws_session_key)

    create_table_template = read_template(path + '/sql/create_audience_table.sql')
    create_table_sql = create_table_template.render(audience_table=self.audience_table)

    upload_stage = read_template(path + '/sql/upload_audience_stage.sql')
    upload_stage = upload_stage.render(audience_table=self.audience_table)

    try:
        self.utilSf.runQuery(self.sfoptions, parquet_stage)
        self.utilSf.runQuery(self.sfoptions, create_table_sql)
        self.utilSf.runQuery(self.sfoptions, upload_stage)
    except Exception as e:
        self.logger.exception(e)
        raise e

    self.logger.info('write_from_audience_parquet_to_snowflake completed successfully')
```

The error is:

```
An error occurred while calling z:net.snowflake.spark.snowflake.Utils.runQuery.
: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.Hashtable.put(Hashtable.java:460)
    at net.snowflake.spark.snowflake.JDBCWrapper.getConnector(SnowflakeJDBCWrapper.scala:141)
    at net.snowflake.spark.snowflake.Utils$.getJDBCConnection(Utils.scala:244)
    at net.snowflake.spark.snowflake.Utils$.getJDBCConnection(Utils.scala:249)
    at net.snowflake.spark.snowflake.Utils$.runQuery(Utils.scala:391)
    at net.snowflake.spark.snowflake.Utils.runQuery(Utils.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Please find the complete error log [here](https://gist.github.com/arverma007/a0a8d9d8c3f249cc98f4c74c789a7302)

I have read that this happens because of the scala versioning issue that spark provides. I am using spark 2.4.5 with externally added hadoop 3.1.2. Also, I am using these snowflake jars:

> spark-snowflake_2.11-2.4.10-spark_2.4.jar
>
> snowflake-ingest-sdk-0.9.5.jar
>
> snowflake-jdbc-3.6.15.jar

If anymore details is needed please let me know through comments.

Comment: Any comfort in moving your python version to 3.5+?

Answer (score 1):

The error happens when it tries to connect to Snowflake. I suggest to check the values in "self.sfoptions" to make sure all required options are specified correctly. Below is an example:

```
sfOptions = {
  "sfURL" : "<account_name>.<cloud_domain>",
  "sfAccount" : "<account_name>",
  "sfUser" : "<user_name>",
  "sfPassword" : "<password>",
  "sfDatabase" : "<database>",
  "sfSchema" : "<schema>",
  "sfWarehouse" : "<warehouse>",
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you are using an old version of snowflake spark connectors and JDBC driver. Please test with the latest snowflake spark connector (2.7.0-spark_2.4) and JDBC driver (3.12.2)

https://search.maven.org/classic/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22net.snowflake%22%20AND%20a%3A%22spark-snowflake_2.11%22

https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/net/snowflake/snowflake-jdbc/3.12.2/

If you are able to reproduce the issue with the latest connectors and drivers then please open a case with us with logs. Thanks!

Comment: Still getting the same error. Made the following changes:-
1)Ran with spark 2.4.5 scala 2.12 (rather than 2.11 version used earlier)version.
2)Jars used:- snowflake-jdbc-3.12.2.jar, spark-snowflake_2.12-2.7.0-spark_2.4.jar, snowflake-ingest-sdk-0.9.6.jar ||

LOGS: https://gist.github.com/arverma007/bcb8d92ec71185259c5de04f74d33488